# Product/Exponential Adjunction in Category of Compactly Generated Hausdorff Spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

We have the functor $K:\bf{Hauss}\to \bf{CGHauss}$ which assigns to each Hausdorff space, its Kellyfication. Then, we can define a product $\square :\bf{CGHauss}\times \bf{CGHauss}\to \bf{CGHauss}$ by $X\square Y=K(X\times Y).$

The proof that $[Z\square Y,X]\cong [Z,X^Y]$ then proceeds in the usual way by showing that the evaluation $e:X^Y\square Y\to X$ is universal:

for $h:Z\square Y\to X$ one defines $k:Z\to X^Y$ by $kz(y)=h(z,y)$  and then shows that $z\mapsto kz$ is continuous. MacLane does this by asserting that it is enough to consider the compact-open topology on $Y^X.$ Why is this so? Why does it suffice to work in a weaker topology?

Comment: I believe the point is to use that $Z $ is compactly generated.

Comment: I tried restricting $k$ to a given compact $C$ in $Z$ but I still had to use the compact-open topology to prove continuity. I think I am missing an (obvious?) topological fact.